# How to use OpenMP in my MEX-file without crashing MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab, openmp, mex

I built a Windows MEX-file from Visual Studio 2019. My MATLAB version is R2019a. The code just does some "sort" to the two input matlab array. This is an example which I try to use with OpenMP. "test.cpp"

```cpp
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{ 
    mxDouble *p0 = mxGetDoubles(prhs[0]);
    mwSize size0 = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
    mxDouble* p1 = mxGetDoubles(prhs[1]);
    mwSize size1 = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[1]);
    vector<vector<int>> v(2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size0; i++) {
        v[0].push_back(int(*p0++));
    };
    for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        v[1].push_back(int(*p1++));
    };
#pragma omp parallel for 
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sort(v[i].begin(), v[i].end());
    };


    plhs[0] = mxCreateCellMatrix(2, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        mxArray* str = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, v[i].size(), mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
        copy(v[i].begin(), v[i].end(), mxGetPr(str));
        mxSetCell(plhs[0], i, mxDuplicateArray(str));
        mxDestroyArray(str);
    };
    return;
}
```

My test M-file is:

```
a1= [1,2,3,4,5];
a2= [1,1,1,1];
result = test(a1,a2);
clear mex;
```

The ideal output will be a 2*1 cell in `result`. If I remove the `# pragma` line the MEX-file works well. If I add it,MATLAB crashed. I have been trying to find the problem for several days and have not find any solution. 
Besides,

1. I have choose the OpenMP support key to "yes" in my Visual Studio.
2. I don't use `mexPrintf` in my code. I heard that function will crash the MEX-file with OpenMP.
3. I have installed the Intel Studio parallel XE 2019 and update 5 of Matlab R2019a. Perhaps I made a wrong parallel domain definition. I don't want to include the last part from `plhs[0] = mxCreateCellMatrix(2, 1);`into the `#pragma` parallel part. As the codes above, am I do it right?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call any `mx...` or `mex...` functions in the parallel part of your code*. You must get pointers to the all the data before the parallel section, including creating output arrays and getting their pointers, then do only your computations in parallel.

---

* The rule given here is overly broad, some `mx...` functions might be OK to use in a parallel section, as indicated in [James Tursa’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041709/how-to-use-openmp-in-my-mex-file-without-crashing-matlab/58043813?noredirect=1#comment102640100_58043813). I prefer not guessing and keeping the rules simple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the above example, I think I did nothing in the parallel section.Do you mean I need to remove all the pointers and arrays before the openmp parallel section?

Comment: I thought you were calling `mxCreateCellMatrix` in the parallel section. Do you have Update 3? That update added support for your compiler, earlier versions of MATLAB do not support that compiler. Might be another thing to look into. See https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/system-requirements-release-2019a-supported-compilers.pdf

Comment: At first, I recognize I used the curly brace wrongly. But after I modified it, it still gives the error. I remove the curly brace after `#pragma omp parallel for`, so the only following `for` loop is influenced by the Openmp. The last `for` loop containing mx-functions is not in parallel mode, I think. (if I am wrong, please point it out.). It has not been OK. I am updating my Intel Parallel Studio XE. For my slow downloading speed, I will update this question ASAP. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I have installed the intel studio parallel XE 2019 and update 5 of matlab. It is better now. `#pragma omp parallel for` with an empty for loop works well. But I put the vector manipulation codes in to the #pragma omp parallel for`, it still errors. I feel I must do something wrong with defining the parallel domain.  Could you give me some advice?

Comment: The mx... or mex... function restriction is for functions that invoke the MATLAB Memory Manager for anything since that isn't thread safe. The mx... functions that simply inquire should be OK (e.g., mxIsDouble, mxIsSparse, mxGetData, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the perfect solution. I just made some correction for the codes and succeeded in building the mexw64 inside Matlab. As for compiling the code in visual studio, the mex rans very low.(VS built 15s and Matlab built 0.4s.I could not figure out why. ) 
At first, I corrected two critical errors.

1. using the curly brace for `#pragma...` correctly. The left curly brace must not directly after `#pragma omp parallel`. It should be in a new line. As below,

```
#pragma omp parallel
{ 
#pragma omp for
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sort(v[i].begin(), v[i].end());
    };
}
```

2 . In the parallel loop, I can't use the `mwIndex` type index. It must be `int` type. This error not happens in the codes in these questions. I just note it down.

Then I used `mex  -v COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS /openmp" test.cpp;` to build the mex file. I just suggest not to build and apply the mex in one m file. My Matlab crashed sometimes. I don't know the reason. I just succeeded in the way separating them, even sounds very weird.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! The `mwIndex` thing is weird, it’s just an alias for `long long int`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you so much for your help and edit of my question. I learned a lot not only the code, but also the marks.